# Nativescript Custom search bar

Tags: nativescript, styling, searchbar

is there anyway to customize the search-bar element that NativeScript provides ?
and add some buttons in it.

am trying to get something like this (the search-bar in this app)

[image]

I've been searching a bit but found nothing about it.

Answer (score 2):

Basic demo here: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=y6iFw9

You can always hide default action bar with `actionBarHidden="true` on your `<page>` element and then create your own action bar. In this case you can use `GridLayout` and put each element in its own column. Something like:

```
<Page actionBarHidden="true>
<StackLayout>
  <GridLayout rows="auto columns="auto, *, auto, auto, auto>
   <Label col="0 text="Menu"/>
   <TextField col="1></TextField>
   <Label col="2 text="icon1"/>
   <Label col="3 text="icon2"/>
   <Label col="4 text="icon3"/>
  </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Just replace labels with your icons, and add `@tap="yourFunction` to fire when icon is pressed. To turn labels into icons you can use package like Fonticon.

Answer (score 0):

The search-bar from tns-core-modules doesn't provide what you're looking for (see the API at https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_ui_search_bar_). I'd recommend to implement the component yourself.

Comment: does that mean i'll have to write android and iOS code ?  cause that's not an option, is it possible to accomplish  it with pure nativescript code ?

Comment: Not at all, it would be javascript or typescript. You could have a look at the nativescript tutorial here: https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-0 or, when using nativescript with angular, here: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-0

Comment: (facepalm), yeah obviously, when I said purely nativescript it meant (JS/TS, XML, CSS) nothing more...